# Opening a table in Microsoft Access with VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to load a table from Microsoft Access and paste it into Excel cells with VBA.

My path is correctly finding my .accdb file and does error until the first Cells(row x).Value = statement.

The "OpenRecordset" method not referencing a table, makes me feel like I shouldn't be passing in the name of the table- or using a different method altogether.

I get an error: "Run-time error '3265' Application-defined or object-defined error

Here is my code below:

```
Sub ImportAccessButton()
Dim row As Integer
Dim dbPassengerCarMileage As Database
Dim rstPassengerCarMileage As Recordset
    row = 3
    Set dbPassengerCarMileage = OpenDatabase(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Cars.accdb")
    Set rstPassengerCarMileage = dbPassengerCarMileage.OpenRecordset("Amber")
    If Not rstPassengerCarMileage.BOF Then
        Do Until rstPassengerCarMileage.EOF
            Cells(row, 1).Value = rstPassengerCarMileage!MAKE
            Cells(row, 2).Value = rstPassengerCarMileage!Model
            Cells(row, 3).Value = rstPassengerCarMileage!VOL
            Cells(row, 4).Value = rstPassengerCarMileage!HP
            Cells(row, 5).Value = rstPassengerCarMileage!MPG
            Cells(row, 6).Value = rstPassengerCarMileage!SP
            Cells(row, 7).Value = rstPassengerCarMileage!WT
            row = row + 1
            rstPassengerCarMileage.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    'Close database and Cleanup objects
    rstPassengerCarMileage.Close
    dbPassengerCarMileage.Close
    Set rstPassengerCarMileage = Nothing
    Set dbPassengerCarMileage = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error? Does it loop once or does it fails instatly?

Comment: Fails instantly, never gets past the first Cell method call on the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses ADODB. The CopyFromRecordset command speeds up.

```
Sub ImportAccessButton()

    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSQL As String

    set Ws = ActiveSheet

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Cars.accdb" & ";"

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Amber"

    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

    If Not Rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            .Range("a2").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(2, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a" & 3).CopyFromRecordset Rs
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```